# WixSharp including appsettings, regardless of predicate

Tags: c#, predicate, wixsharp

Im using WixSharp to build my installer. In my project, I have this :

```
new Files(
    new Feature("RootFilesFeature"),
    Path.Combine(C_SERVICE_RELEASE_PATH,"*.*"),
    (lFilename) => !lFilename.StartsWith("appsettings", true)
)
```

Regardless of that predicate, I still get appsettings.json and appsettings.development.json installed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because `lFilename` is the name of the file including it's path.

If it's possible in your case then use `Contains`

```
new Files(
    new Feature("RootFilesFeature"),
    Path.Combine(C_SERVICE_RELEASE_PATH,"*.*"),
    (lFilename) => !lFilename.Contains("appsettings")
)
```

or `EndsWith`

```
new Files(new Feature("RootFilesFeature"),
    Path.Combine(C_SERVICE_RELEASE_PATH, "*.*"),
    (lFilename) => !lFilename.EndsWith("appsettings.json", true) || 
                   !lFilename.EndsWith("appsettings.development.json", true)
)
```

Comment: So your code didn't exactly work as is (I still needed that path in), but you were right; the filename was not only the filename, but the entire path. When I changed my predicate to contains, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude both "appsettings.json" and "appsettings.development.json" you have to put && between them and not ||

```
new Files(new Feature("RootFilesFeature"),
    Path.Combine(C_SERVICE_RELEASE_PATH, "*.*"),
    (lFilename) => !lFilename.EndsWith("appsettings.json", true) && 
                   !lFilename.EndsWith("appsettings.development.json", true)
)
```